# Passing props between components Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have 3 components A , B , C and . C is child of B and B is child of A . How can i pass props from A to C directly without bringing B . Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll need to do something like this:

```
<B {...this.props} />
```

Or use something like [redux](http://rackt.github.io/redux/) and have a global store of application state with `A` and `C` both being 'smart' components.